# -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory <--Trying to install arping

Tags: linux, bash, installation

I am quite new to linux and I was trying to install arping on my raspberry pi (Rasbian).

So I downloaded the latest arping version from here (https://github.com/ThomasHabets/arping/releases), put it on my raspberry pi and extracted the .tar.gz file.

After that I tried to follow the instructions given in the Install file (https://github.com/ThomasHabets/arping/blob/arping-2.x/INSTALL)

When I try to follow the instructions I get this error:

```
[15:16:19] root@Raspbian:~$ cd arping-arping-2.19
[15:16:27] root@Raspbian:~/arping-arping-2.19$ ls
bootstrap.sh  doc    fuzz        INSTALL  Makefile.am         README
configure.ac  extra  HACKING.md  LICENSE  Makefile.am.common  src
[15:16:28] root@Raspbian:~/arping-arping-2.19$ ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
[15:17:51] root@Raspbian:~/arping-arping-2.19$ make  
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[15:17:51] root@Raspbian:~/arping-arping-2.19$ sudo make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
[15:17:59] root@Raspbian:~/arping-arping-2.19$
```

Why is it not working ? What did I do wrong ?

kind regards

Comment: Try running `autoconf`

Comment: Trying running autoconf returns this: -bash: autoconf: command not found

Comment: Install `autoconf automake libtool` . And then please run `./bootstrap.sh` to create the script `configure` . I.e. when no file `configure`, the command `./configure` is of course impossible : `./"file"` means run a file in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks alot @KnudLarsen this did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

`configure.ac is not configure, you need to make then sudo make install to configure and install that type of source code.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. also ./configure.ac is not working. If you meant that.